# Butterscotch Sauce consistency

Tags: sauce, sugar, butter, consistency

I keep getting quite a mixed bag when it comes to butterscotch sauce; sometimes it's runny, sometimes it's thick (as I want it).  Other times it gets lumps in it, or simply clumps to the side of the pan while having a runny consistency in the middle of it.

I tend to start with 7 muscovado : 2 butter : 5 cream.

I melt the butter, dissolve the sugar thoroughly, then stir in the cream, allowing it to bubble lightly, not boil, though I have tried this, also (I don't use a thermometer - I don't have one!).

Why should I get such varied results on the consistency?

Comment: It's the fact you aren't using a thermometer. Consistency comes from a consistent method and consistent temperatures and times.

Comment: @GdD: Should I be using a thermometer for a simple sauce? It's not as if it's toffee or similar that I'm making.

Comment: I'd recommend it yes @Paul. Butterscotch is easy to make, but if you want really good consistency then you need to weigh the ingredients and control the temperature.

Comment: @GdD: Okay, thank-you. If you put that in an answer I'll credit you...

Comment: I'm not going to put that as an answer because I don't think it covers your case completely @Paul. A good answer will cover why you are getting lumps, i.e. what's going wrong.

Comment: unless you're an old pro, you basically _need_ to use a thermometer.

Comment: @dandavis: I must admit, I'll have to buy one, anyway, as I'm going to be making sweets and toffee at some point.  May as well bite the bullet-hard toffee.